# HttpHandler does not send image at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

My images suddenly will not work in my application.  During design time they show up perfectly.  But all my images are not there during runtime.  I have them in an Images folder.  I am using "~/" to go back to the root directory.  This used to work and for some reason stopped working.  Any ideas?

```
<asp:Image ID="imgFirstElected" runat="server" 
          ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar_icon.gif" style="cursor:pointer;" />
```

Edit:

Ok i just found out it is because of my ImageHandler.  If i remove this code from my web.config my images show up again.  Any idea how i can fix this issue?

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.bmp" type="CurrentFigures.HttpImageHandler,CurrentFigures"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.jpg" type="CurrentFigures.HttpImageHandler,CurrentFigures"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.gif" type="CurrentFigures.HttpImageHandler,CurrentFigures"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.png" type="CurrentFigures.HttpImageHandler,CurrentFigures"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Edit: Image Handler Code

```
public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        int imageid = Parser.GetInt(context.Request.QueryString["ImID"]);
        ProfileImage image = new ProfileImage(Parser.GetInt(imageid));

        if (imageid > 0)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            Stream strm = ShowImage(imageid);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);

            while (byteSeq > 0)
            {
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
                byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
            }
        }

        /*
        string imageid = context.Request.QueryString["ImID"];
        ProfileImage image = new ProfileImage(Parser.GetInt(imageid));

        context.Response.BinaryWrite(image.ImageData);
        context.Response.End(); */
    }

    public Stream ShowImage(int imageID)
    {
        ProfileImage image = new ProfileImage(Parser.GetInt(imageID));

        try
        {
            return new MemoryStream(image.ImageData);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: We need to know what's going on in `HttpImageHandler` class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to calls `context.Response.Flush();` after your `while` loop ends